# SQL Server Configuration Manager is not in my PC

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

This may look like a repeat of an already existing question but it isn't.
I am trying to work with an Azure-SQL database. I attempted to log in both from Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio and I get the following error:
[image: Error message]

Now, after some basic troubleshooting I made sure that the firewall in the server had my IP recorded, so that isn't the issue here.
Also, just for trying I did a mobile hotspot from my phone and it logged in with no issues. So for some reason my home network isn't letting me work this.

Now before I reached out to my ISP (which would be hell on earth) I did some more digging and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641107/6461236

That users suggests that the solution is to go into "SQL Server Configuration Manager" and modify port permissions. But when I attempt to find this, it's not in my PC. I have a Windows 10 PC and I have searched *everywhere* and I just can't find this SQL Server Configuration Manager. Check out what I get on my Computer Management window: 
[image]

So the bottom line is that I have installed both Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Management Studio 2017 and my computer doesn't have a SQL Server Configuration Manager. After researching a bit more all that I have found is that *it should be there*.

What did I miss? How can I solve this pesky problem? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Since I could log in with no issues with my phone as a hotspot and the issues only present themselves when using my home WiFi it seems that this is a problem with my home network and not with my PC or Azure. Any tips? Should a phone call to my ISP solve this?

Comment: If you installed *only* Management Studio, then you **only** installed the GUI Frontend tool to manage SQL Server - but you didn't actually install the **SQL Server database engine**. The Configuration Manager stuff is part of the **core engine install** - not the management tools.....

Comment: And what exactly is your question here, are you trying to use SSCM to manage a Azure SQL database(PAAS)?? That is not possible, and all management task should be done via Azure Management Portal/Azure CLI/REST API.

Comment: I want to use Visual Studio/SSMS to view/set tables and run queries. Once again, I have no trouble doing this with my phone hotspot but for some reason my home network is giving me this problem. I understand I need to install the database engine to get the Configuration Manager but is it necessary to solve my problem?

Comment: No. Configuration Manager is to configure SQL Server installations. You are running Azure, and as @linleng mentioned, that is administrated through Azure Management Portal

Comment: Thanks. After some more digging the fact that I can login with my phone's hotspot and not with my home wifi seems to indicate there is an issue with my network/ISP. Apparently it's blocking port 1433 to communicate to the server. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my network firewall was set to "max" and was therefore blocking any outbound traffic on port 1433 (which is necessary to connect to SQL Azure). The solution was to modify the router firewall to allow for communication on this port to be outbound.